# Good security practice for remote to local backup using rsync

Tags: ssh, security, rsync, backup, vps

I would like to perform a manual backup of a remote VPS (Debian 12) to my laptop using `rsync`. I want to backup the single files and directories to easily inspect them locally, and not e.g. a VM snapshot.

The VPS' filesystem is not really large, I do not need to backup all of it but quite a few directories that require root read permissions (many `/var` and `/etc` subdirs at a very minimum, including some files with `-rw-rw----` permissions such as certain secret keys and certificates). I don't really care if user permissions are not kept from VPS to laptop. `ssh` on the VPS is quite hardened (only one user allowed, no root, passwordless etc). The VPS user can eventually `sudo`.

Easy solution would be to enable passwordless `ssh` root login and `rsync` from my laptop to the server using root, but I don't really like the idea.

I thought maybe a slightly better option could be:

1. create a "backup" user on the VPS without `/home`
2. add it to the root group
3. enable passwordless `ssh` login for it, but
4. use the `ssh` option that limits the kind of commands that this user can run

Is there a better option? If not, how do I do (1)-(4) above correctly?

Comment: "_I don't really like the idea_" - what's your concern with a direct certificate-based login as root to the VPS?

Comment: "_create a "backup" user on the VPS_" - given your earlier requirement "_quite a few directories that require root read permissions_" how would this user be able to copy the necessary files? Or are you suggesting you'd relax the permissions to allow root group to read? That can't work for some secure system files

Comment: Thanks for the question. It's probably a matter of taste, but at a very minimum I would have to take extra precautions to store and manage the root SSH credential securely. In the future I would also like to log SSH connections according to user/scope (for now it's only one SSH user but this will change)

Comment: Ah you're right about permissions, that was a typo, apologies, I meant -rw-rw----